# pip: install dependencies of dependencies

Tags: python, dependencies, pip

I would like to manually install all the requirements of a Python package I'm writing. To this end, I created the file `requirements.txt` and added the dependencies, line by line:

```
$ cat requirements.txt
meshio
numpy
```

When running

```
$ pip install -r requirements.txt
```

those two packages are installed alright, but I noticed that the dependencies of meshio aren't (i.e., whatever is listed in its `requirements.txt`). Not surprising, how is pip supposed to know?

Is there a mechanism for installing the entire dependency tree with pip?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Turns out for the dependencies to be installed, the packages needs to list its dependencies as

```
install_requires=[
    'numpy',
    'pyyaml'
],
```

as part of `setup()` in `setup.py`, not in `requirements.txt`.

Comment: if there are transitive dependencies, to ensure pip get the right versions for all of them, you need to analyse all the setup.py files, and `pip-tools` can do it for you

Answer (score 7):

You may be interested by [pip-tools](https://github.com/nvie/pip-tools), a python package that can be used to build a `requirements.txt` file that takes into account all underlying dependencies. It can be installed via pip:

```sh
pip install --upgrade pip  # pip-tools needs pip>=6.
pip install pip-tools
```

Once installed, you can use the `pip-compile` command to generate your requirements file. For example, suppose you work on a Flask project. You would have to do the following:

Write the following line to a file:

```
Flask
```

Run `pip-compile <your-file>`. It will produce your requirements.txt, with all the dependencies pinned. You can re-run `pip-compile` to update the packages. Your output file will look like this:

```
#
# This file is autogenerated by pip-compile
# Make changes in requirements.in, then run this to update:
#
#    pip-compile <your-file>
#
flask==0.10.1
itsdangerous==0.24        # via flask
jinja2==2.7.3             # via flask
markupsafe==0.23          # via jinja2
werkzeug==0.10.4          # via flask
```

Comment: I was already using pip-tools for development, I didn't think of it to install things in production. But it comes in handy ! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you need. But this is how I solve this problem. I create a **virtual environment** for each of my python projects.

```sh
cd my_project_folder
virtualenv venv # choose the python interpreter you need ;)
source venv/bin/activate
```

Then I install all the needed packages for the project.

```
pip install <what ever packages you need>
```

If you then need to create a requirements.txt you can use this command

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt  # including the installed version of each package
```

To leave a **virtual environment** just type `deactivate`. Hope this helps you...

This is also in detail described [here](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/)